# Twilio iOS client - keep active in background

Tags: ios, twilio

Is there any special configuration necessary to keep the Twilio iOS client active in the background? I have enabled the "VoIP" and "audio" permissions, but I notice that my app is exited after about 10 minutes of being in the background. Note that I have disabled sounds from playing by 'TCDevice' and also made some changes to the AVAudioSession configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The 10 minute limit is set by the iOS limit on background processes. Does it still go inactive after 10 minutes if you're actively receiving/making a call? It shouldn't in that case.

Comment: iOS voip permissions are supposed let the app the run in the background forever to maintain the voip socket, so it shouldn't matter if you're actively receiving or making a call.

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by the Twilio SDK, it calls setKeepAliveTimeout to keep the App running in the background.  I have tested this and can confirm it keeps my App alive for days.